# Use dropdown to pass Primary ID to PHP form using MYSQLi not working

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, dropdown, hidden

Using a AddTeamPlayer.php page to pass the selected value from a form dropdown via a hidden field to another AddPlayer.php.  The value is not sending.  Code will be posted from all three pages.  The result, error, is showing an empty value when trying to send the selected hidden value.

**AddTeamPlayer.php**

```
<select name="myselectbox">
<option>Select</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT TeamName, TeamID FROM Team ORDER BY TeamName";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option>' . $row['TeamName'] .' '. $row['TeamID'] . ' </option>';

'<input type="hidden" name="hiddenTeamID" value="('. $row['TeamID'] . ')" >';    
    
}
?>
</select>
```

**AddPlayer.php**

```
//Team from the dropdown on AddTeamPlayerData.php page - hidden variable
$TeamID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['hiddenTeamID']);

echo "hiddenteamid is $TeamID";


// insert PLAYER table data from form
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, Number, TeamID) VALUES ('$PlayerFirstName', '$PlayerLastName', '$PlayerNumber', '$TeamID')";
```

**ERROR Received**

> hiddenteamid is
>
> ERROR: Could not execute Player data... INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, Number, TeamID) VALUES ('pfn', 'pln', '3', '').
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`playmak3_pitchcountstats`.`Player`, CONSTRAINT `Player_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TeamID`) REFERENCES `Team` (`TeamID`))

Comment: We need to see more of `AddTeamPlayer.php` and how you submit that `form` (?; we can't see the `form` tags) to `AddPlayer.php`

Comment: You cannot put `<input>` inside `<select>`

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `hiddenTeamID` value in parentheses? That's going to literally send something like `"(1)"`

Comment: If <select name="myselectbox"> is out side  <form> in AddTeamPlayer.php than you can use "onChange" jQuery to set selected value in "hidden" field. You can not add hidden field in between select tag.

Answer (score 0):

**N.B.** As @Phil rightly pointed out you've actually got your `hidden` field inside of the `select` and therefore this initial fix won't work. However, I'm going to leave it here anyway....

You have an error in your `PHP` code:

```
1>   $sql = "SELECT TeamName, TeamID FROM Team ORDER BY TeamName";
2>   $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
3>   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
4>   echo '<option>' . $row['TeamName'] .' '. $row['TeamID'] . ' </option>';
5> 
6>   '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenTeamID" value="('. $row['TeamID'] . ')" >';    
7>     
8>   }
```

On line `4` you have a semi-colon at the end of the line terminating the `echo`. Which means that line `6` is never echoed out. Therefore, from a front end perspective it looks as you'd expect **but** the hidden field isn't there and so doesn't get passed on.

Remove the semi-colon and replace it with `.` instead.

### Fixing the code

#### Basic Fix

*AddTeamPlayer.php*

```
<select name="myselectbox">
<option disabled hidden selected>Select a team...</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT TeamName, TeamID FROM Team ORDER BY TeamName";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $teamid   = $row["TeamID"];
        $teamname = $row["TeamName"];
        echo "<option value=\"{$teamid}\">{$teamname}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

*AddPlayer.php*

```
//Team from the dropdown on AddTeamPlayerData.php page
$teamid = (int)$_POST["myselectbox"]; // Assuming that TeamID is an integer... Casting it to int is the only escaping you need

echo "Team ID is: ".$teamid;

// Insert PLAYER table data from form
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, Number, TeamID) VALUES ('{$PlayerFirstName}', '{$PlayerLastName}', '{$PlayerNumber}', {$teamid})";
```

However, even this leaves you *potentially* open to problems. It's often quoted (on this site) that *"escaping your input isn't enough"* to protect you from malicious behaviour.

As such I strongly suggest you look into **Prepared Statements** with `mysqli` or `PDO`

#### Improving the code

**mysqli**

```
$data= [
    $_POST["FirstName"],    // First name from form
    $_POST["LastName"],     // Last name from form
    $_POST["Number"],       // Number from form
    $_POST["myselectbox"]   // Team id from select box
];

$sql   = "INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, Number, TeamID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";    // SQL statement using `?` as place holders
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);        // Prepare query
$query->bind_param("ssii", ...$data);   // Bind parameters, setting data type, using PHPs unpacking operator ...
$query->execute();                      // Execute the query
```

**PDO**

```
$data= [
    $_POST["FirstName"],    // First name from form
    $_POST["LastName"],     // Last name from form
    $_POST["Number"],       // Number from form
    $_POST["myselectbox"]   // Team id from select box
];

$sql   = "INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, Number, TeamID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";    // SQL statement using `?` as place holders
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);   // Prepare query
$query->execute($data);         // Bind parameters and execute query
```

Comment: The `<input>` should come before or after the `<select>` tag, not within it

Comment: @Phil truthfully it shouldn't come at all.. It should be a `value` added to the `option` by the looks of it.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. The more I look at OP's code, the more confusing it gets. Looks like OP should just use `$_REQUEST["myselectbox"]` instead

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The changes were made using the "Fixing the Code" section above. The TeamID is now returning, but not returning the correct integer.   For instance, it is returning 9 when there is not a TeamID of 9 in the DB.  Additionally, when other Selected TeamID's are returned, they return a 0.

Comment: @bgstewart7 could you add the updated code in the question so that I can see what we're now working with?

Comment: @Steven - I figured this out.  There was a 'disabled' option left in the Select form.  Once removed, it worked great.  Thank you for responding.

Comment: @bgstewart7 No problem!